# SSL CA Certificates - LibCurl C Language (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, ssl, certificate, libcurl

Im working with a WebService and I still cannot authenticate peer certificates.
Im using libCurl to C language, this is the output:

> Cannot Perform Post, Err: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

So I've tried to test connection through openssl command:

`openssl s_client -connect homnfce.sefaz.am.gov.br:443 -cert cert.pem -key nfcek.pem`

Then :
`Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

Going further I looked around to server certificates, and noticed that they have a cert chain.
So I've downloaded them and added using keytool:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file cert1.cer -alias mykey
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file cert2.cer -alias mykey2
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file cert3.cer -alias mykey3
```

Even with these changes, I still can't authenticate peer certificates.

I think it can indicate an error while setting CURLOPTs, heres a extract of code:

```
 if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1) != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://homnfce.sefaz.am.gov.br/nfce-services-nac/services/NfeStatusServico2?wsdl") != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443) != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "cert.pem") != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "nfcek.pem") != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  sprintf(szCertPath, "%s","/home/CAcerts/");
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, szCertPath) != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, iLen) != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, szMyPw) != CURLE_OK ) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, pfChk) != CURLE_OK ) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pfAnswer) != CURLE_OK ) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, iOnlineServerTimeout) != CURLE_OK ) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT) failed");
    return -1;
  }
  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1) != CURLE_OK) {
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTrace("curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1) failed");
    return __LINE__;
  }

  if ( (res = curl_easy_perform(curl)) != CURLE_OK ){
    if ( DEBUG_DETAILS ) vTraceStr("iNFCE_CurlReq(): Cannot Perform Post, Err: %s\n", (char *)curl_easy_strerror(res));
    return -1;
  }
```

Something important is the fact that I **can't** use insecure mode option ingnore peer authentication (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = 0 ).

Any ideas? What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us what SSL library your curl is using? I thought `keytool` was for Java key stores?

Comment: How can I discover which SSL lib curl is using? I **think** it uses OpenSSL default.

Comment: Try `ldd` on your `libcurl.so`. Have you tried adding those three certificates to the `CURLOPT_CAPATH` (`/home/CAcerts/` in your example) and running OpenSSL c_rehash as specified here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAPATH.html?

Comment: Im not using libcurl dinamically linked, I mean, i dont use dlopen to use functions of libcurl.so, Im adding the curl.h Header file.
Btw I checked out the ldd of my libcurl.so and it uses libssl.so
Im working on c_rehash functions to openssl

Comment: @lmz Thank you, I still cannot authenticate, but I've c_rehash(ed) the directory:

`c_rehash  .
Doing .
acserprov3.pem => 707978d0.0
icpbrasilv2.pem => 1e54e6fa.0
serproacfv3.pem => 1526e8dd.0
`

Comment: Are any of your .pem files an actual self-signed root certificate (subject == issuer)? OpenSSL by default tries to build the trust chain up to a self-signed root certificate. Check http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Verify-intermediate-certificate-td27976.html for a discussion.

Comment: @lmz, i've advanced in this point. 
I got a pack of certificates of the server, that I used to generate a cacert file.
Then I Added the CAPATH and CAINFO to curlopts.
So now I got this message:
`Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`
Ive used keytool to import the certificates into cacert file, with this command :
`keytool -import -alias root -file cer1.cer -keystore cacerts`
`keytool -import -alias root1 -file cer2.cer -keystore cacerts`
`keytool -import -alias root2 -file cer3.cer -keystore cacerts`

Comment: In advance Ive checked my cert.pem and I got:
`subject=/C=BR/ST=SP/L=BARUERI/O=ICP-Brasil/OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB/OU=RFB e-CNPJ A1/OU=AR SERASA/CN=CONECTO SISTEMAS LTDA:05113966000159
issuer=/C=BR/O=ICP-Brasil/OU=Secretaria da Receita Federal do Brasil - RFB/CN=AC SERASA RFB v2
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it.
Actually it was a problem with Servers CAs. 
Ive download a certificate chain from host, then ive used openssl commands to convert:

```
  openssl x509 -in raiz_v2.cer -out raiz_v2.pem
  openssl x509 -in ac_certsign_g6.cer -out ac_certsign_g6.pem
  openssl x509 -in ac_certsign_mult_g5.cer -out ac_certsign_mult_g5.pem
```

So ive unified them using:

```
 cat raiz_v2.pem > cacert.pem
 cat ac_certsign_g6.pem >> cacert.pem
 cat ac_certsign_mult_g5.pem >> cacert.pem
```

And then ive pointed to cacert.pem using CURLOPT_CAINFO option.