# Fix for Octave urlread causing Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, octave, libcurl, urlread

## Question

How to the fix (not workaround) for Octave (suppose libcurl bundled with octave) urlread causing ***Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates***?

Having read [pkg install from forge in windows](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/pkg-install-from-forge-in-windows-td4680633.html), it looks the Octave maintainer is aware of the issue with Octave 4.0 but it seems no fix is available.

## Issue

It looks the urlread of Octave on Windows does not work for HTTPS because the server certificate of such as https://octave.sourceforge.io cannot be authenticated with the trusted certificates which urlread (which seems to call curl) refers to.

For example, share\octave\4.2.0\m\pkg\private\get_forge_pkg.m line 64 is causing the issue when trying to run ***pkg install -forge*** to install packages.

```
## Try get the list of all packages.
[html, succ] = urlread ("http://packages.octave.org/list_packages.php");    
if (! succ)
  error ("get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection");
endif
```

Running urlread from the command window shows the error below.

```
>> [html, status, msg] = urlread ("http://packages.octave.org/list_packages.php");
>> msg
msg = Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Tried google.com over HTTPS and the same.

```
>> [html, status, msg] = urlread ("https://google.com");
>> msg
msg = Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

IE and Google Chrome root certificates can verify the sourceforge certificate.

[image]

[image]

Tried system as below.

```
#[html, succ] = urlread ("http://packages.octave.org/list_packages.php");
sURLLink="https://octave.sourceforge.io/list_packages.php"
command=['curl --insecure ','"',sURLLink,'"'];
[succ, html] = system(command)
#if (! succ)
if (succ != 0)
  error ("get_forge_pkg: could not read URL, please verify internet connection");
endif
```

However it caused another error.

```
>> pkg install -forge symbolic
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   559  100   559    0     0    389      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   393
sURLLink = https://octave.sourceforge.io/list_packages.php
succ = 0
html = bim
bsltl
cgi
....

error: get_forge_pkg: package NAME exists, but index page not available
error: called from
    get_forge_pkg at line 74 column 7
    get_forge_download at line 26 column 12
    pkg at line 382 column 29
```

### Related information

- [pkg install from forge in windows](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/pkg-install-from-forge-in-windows-td4680633.html)
- [urlread(), urlwrite() don't work for https pages in Octave for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237960/urlread-urlwrite-dont-work-for-https-pages-in-octave-for-windows)
- [windows libcurl - peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given ca certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752114/windows-libcurl-peer-certificate-cannot-be-authenticated-with-given-ca-certifi)
- [Getting error in Curl - Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682894/getting-error-in-curl-peer-certificate-cannot-be-authenticated-with-known-ca-c)
- [SSL CA Certificates - LibCurl C Language (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719772/ssl-ca-certificates-libcurl-c-language-linux)

### Environment

1. octave-4.2.0-w64 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
2. Octave 4.0.3 on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393

Answer (score 3):

1. You get the "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated" error because your CA store doesn't contain the necessary CA cert. You can get an updated bundle [from here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
2. The reason your attempt to use the curl command line tool doesn't work is that you didn't use [-L, --location](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) option to tell curl to follow redirects, so you just got the 303 response that  `http://packages.octave.org/list_packages.php` returns. If you'd use -L, you'll see that it'll redirect you twice over to a HTTPS:// URL - only to have you be forced to fix case (1) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you provide a bit more detail how and where to update the "CA store" which CURL or Octave library uses? IE or Chrome, or JRE has their own repositories, so I suppose the library which Octave uses has its own.

Comment: As I'm not familiar with Octave I had to be vague on that point. I know libcurl intimately and since that is used, I could talk about those details. libcurl typically loads the "CA bundle" as a file (in PEM format). I suppose the Octave docs should clarify where/how the CA bundle is provided/updated.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it gives the direction to look for. Will look into.

Comment: FYI: Nick provided the cause, fix release, and workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687465.