# Error when installing package - symbolic

Tags: package, octave

For expanding, collecting, factorization and simplification of equations, I'm trying to install the package: `symbolic`<sup>1</sup>, in Octave 4.2.1 (running on Windows 10).

When I execute `pkg install symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz` from the command line I get:

> dirlist(3): out of bound 2
>   error: called from
>   install at line 102 column 19
>   pkg at line 394 column 9

[image]

What is this error? How to install the package?

---

<sup>1. Which is manually downloaded and located in the current working directory: bottom right corner of the first picture.</sup>

<sup>2.I have the required dependencies: `Python` and `Sympy` installed:</sup>

<sup>3. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687465/octave-how-to-install-packages-on-windows).</sup>

[image]

---

Update: Following @Alex338207 suggestions

Just extracted it with 7-Zip (twice: symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz -> symbolic-2.6.0.tar -> symbolic-2.6.0).

Then ran: `pkg install symbolic-2.6.0` and got the following error:

> unpack: FILETYPE must be "gunzip" for a directory
>   error: called from
>   unpack at line 122 column 7
>   untar at line 47 column 5
>   install at line 81 column 9
>   pkg at line 394 column 9

---

Update 2: Following @carandraug suggestions. After modifying the function `install` (`dirlist` right after `[dirlist, err, msg] = readdir (tmpdir);` ), I get:

```
filelist =
{
  [1,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/
  [2,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/CONTRIBUTORS
  [3,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/COPYING
  [4,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/DESCRIPTION
  [5,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/INDEX
  [6,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/Makefile
  [7,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/NEWS
  [8,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/README.md
  [9,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/bin/
  [10,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/bin/winwrapy.bat
  [11,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/inst/
  [12,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/inst/@double/
  ....
  [396,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/misc/
  [397,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/misc/extract_tests_for_matlab.m
  [398,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/misc/my_print_usage.m
  [399,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/misc/octassert.m
  [400,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/misc/octsympy_tests_matlab.m
  [401,1] = symbolic-2.6.0/octave-symbolic.metainfo.xml
}
```

and:

```
dirlist =
{
  [1,1] = .
  [2,1] = ..
}
```

Comment: Can you please run `debug_on_error (1)` before calling `pkg install ...` and examine `tgz` and `dirlist`. Btw, since pkg and install all are .m file and you also want to write .m files it's a good idea to learn basic debugging techniques for .m files.

Comment: I've run `debug_on_error (1)` and then `pkg install symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz`, again. I get the same error message. 
Regarding debugging  - Fair enough. What exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: you should start debugging from this as I've written above

Comment: So you've decided to not debug this issue?

Comment: @Andy Apologies but I couldn't understand what exactly are you suggesting. If you want to expand your comment into an answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Andy debugging the files of Octave itself would have been the last thing that I would have done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pkg` function expects a tar.gz file, that is, an archive of a directory tree (a `.tar` file) which is then gunzipped (compressed, the '.gz').  So you shouldn't have tried to uncompress it yourself.

The error you get comes from [pkg/private/install.m#102](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/1327ea4f5a93/scripts/pkg/private/install.m#l102) which is right after uncompressing the package file.

```
    ## The two first entries of dirlist are "." and "..".
    if (exist (tgz, "file"))
      packdir = fullfile (tmpdir, dirlist{3});
    else
```

The inside of the package should have a single directory, with the package contents, and nothing else.  At this point, `dirlist` should be:

```
{".", "..", the_only_directory_inside_tgz}
```

However, your error says that `dirlist{3}` is out of bounds, so there is no directory after uncompressing the package.  You can see a bit earlier that `dirlist` comes from:

```
    untar (tgz, tmpdir);

    ## Get the name of the directories produced by tar.
    [dirlist, err, msg] = readdir (tmpdir);
    if (err)
      error ("couldn't read directory produced by tar: %s", msg);
    endif

    if (length (dirlist) > 3)
      error ("bundles of packages are not allowed");
    endif
```

So, it's not clear at this point what the issue is.  We can deduce that `readdir` did not fail, so `dirlist` will at least have `.` and `..`.  This suggests me that `untar` found nothing during the uncompressing.

Try replacing that line with:

```
filelist = untar (tgz, tmpdir) # no ; at the end
```

To see what was unpacked.  Also, a few lines below, print out the values of `dirlist` should give you hints about what is going on.

**EDIT:** see answer comments for a *kind of* solution.  Basically, it seems that the `untar` function was failing to uncompressing the package to the specified directory (`C:\...Temp\oct-...`) and was instead uncompressing them to `C:\`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! `filelist` contains 401 elements, so `untar` has found and uncompressed something, however, `dirlist` has only 2 elements: `'.', '..'`. This is strange...

Comment: `dir` is not assigned a third element if it's not already uncompressed, i.e. if  `if (tgz, 'file')`, there is not `dirlist = {".", "..", tgz};`  ?

Comment: @Ziezi `dir` should have been assigned by `readdir` but seems like `readdir` found an empty directory. My guess is something weird on your paths, and that `unpack` did not uncompress the files into `tmpdir`. Try to install with `pkg install -verbose ...` which will tell you where things are.

Comment: Here it's the message after `pkg install -verbose symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz`:
`mkdir (C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\oct-cMFS8z)
untar (symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz, C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\oct-cMFS8z)`

What I've done wrong?

Comment: @Ziezi I'm guessing you are hiding the real value of `bla`. Does it have spaces or any non-ascii characters?

Comment: No. Just a name, consisted of Latin characters. Other strange thing that I just observed is that the uncompressed folder (of the package) is placed in the same directory as Octave (C:\\).

Comment: Try it yourself, and see if it works `untar (path-to-symbolic-targz, some-dir); dirlist = readdir (some-dir);`. I'm guessing that if you can make those work, then you will have your problem solved.

Comment: @Ziezi if you found that the uncompressed files are showing up at `C:\ ` instead of `C:\...Temp\oct-...` then you found the issue.  Octave's `unpack` is failing to do it on the specified directory. Consider reporting a bug and adjust `install.m` so it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error comes from the installation of the package (before any code from the package is actually run).

Octave seems to have trouble reading the file in the compressed directory.
Can you check the size of the file `symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz` ? It should have  239429 bytes. Maybe you should re-download the file. You can also verify its MD5 sum (c24c07222c7bb6770cf2a6dbee653bff) using the tool described here https://superuser.com/a/245776/338207. Check also that your system has enough disk space.

If the file has the right size and the error persists, you can also decompress the file `symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz` (using for example 7-zip). It should contain a single folder also called `symbolic-2.6.0`. Avoid to decompress the files as `symbolic-2.6.0\symbolic-2.6.0\...`.

In octave, you can install the package from the uncompressed folder with these commands:

```
 cd('c:\go\to\the\directory')
```

Where `c:\go\to\the\directory` is the directory containing `symbolic-2.6.0`.
Or use the "current directory" drop-drown menu from the GUI. Then:

```
 ls('symbolic-2.6.0')
```

Verify that you see `inst`, `bin` and `Makefile` among others. Finally:

```
 pkg install symbolic-2.6.0
```

To load the package use:

```
pkg load symbolic
```

If you want to avoid to load the package, you can also install it with:

```
 pkg install -auto symbolic-2.6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Regarding the file: I ran 7-Zip->Test Archive, and the result is: Archives: 1, Packed size: 239429, Files: 1, Size: 1505280 bytes (1MB), There are no errors. 

Now, I'm going to follow the next suggestions.

Comment: Just extracted it with 7-Zip (twice: symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz -> symbolic-2.6.0.tar -> symbolic-2.6.0). Then ran: `pkg install symbolic-2.6.0` and got the following error:

unpack: FILETYPE must be "gunzip" for a directory;
error: called from;
 unpack at line 122 column 7;
 untar at line 47 column 5;
 install at line 81 column 9;
 pkg at line 394 column 9;